# How to create counter variable with if condition

Tags: sas

So I am still a newbie in SAS and therefore any help is greatly appreciated.

I am trying to create 2 counter variables:
1st one - COUNTTREATMENTVISITS that counts +1 whenever FOLDERNAME variable in my dataset has any values except 'Visit 1 Screening 1','Visit 2 Screening 2','Visit 17 Safety FU'
2nd one - COUNTETPATIENT that counts +1 whenever DSTERM2 variable in my dataset has any values except 'Complete'
after getting these 2 counter variables straight I just want to calculate and display in output EEOT_RATE as per the formula :EEOT_RATE=COUNTETPATIENT/(COUNTTREATMENTVISITS/1000)

I already did some SAS code(using Cluepoints platform for clinical trials)  but I can't get past the errors(see below code and error snapshot):

```
data RAND1 (keep= CP_PATIENT CP_REGION CP_CENTER RANDYN RANDYN_STD RANDOMIZED_AT 
RANDOMIZED_AT_INT);
set data_in.rand;
where RANDYN='Yes';
by FOLDERNAME;
retain COUNTTREATMENTVISITS=0;
if FOLDERNAME NOT in('Visit 1 Screening 1','Visit 2 Screening 2','Visit 17 Safety FU') then 
COUNTTREATMENTVISITS+1;
run;

proc sort data = RAND1;
by CP_PATIENT; 
run;

data DS1 (keep = CP_PATIENT CP_REGION CP_CENTER ET DSTERM2 DSCONT FOLDERNAME);
set data_in.DS; 
retain COUNTETPATIENT=0;
if strip(DSTERM2) NE 'Completed' then COUNTETPATIENT+1; 
run;

proc sort data = DS1;
by CP_PATIENT; 
run;

data data_out.output; 
merge RAND1 (in=a) DS1 (in=b);
by CP_PATIENT;
if a;
if CP_PATIENT='' then delete;

EEOT_RATE=COUNTETPATIENT/(COUNTTREATMENTVISITS/1000);
run;
```

[Error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5q4r.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS Syntax for retain statement is:

```
retain COUNTTREATMENTVISITS 0;
```

See documentation here : https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/p0t2ac0tfzcgbjn112mu96hkgg9o.htm#p115mm1hsepln9n11cxtkk7wejim

Comment: Thank you,this solved my problem. Also, would you be so kind and tell me how can I keep EEOT_RATE variable in output to be able to apply a test on it? If I write "data data_out.output(keep = EEOT_RATE)  " it gives error.

Comment: I am not sure that "data data_out.output(keep = EEOT_RATE)" helps your objective. This is syntacticaly correrct (please show the log if you have an error) but it forces the output table to have only one column : EEOT_RATE which makes little sense IMHO. Also: "if CP_PATIENT='' then delete;" could be impemtented better by "where CP_PATIENT ne '' ".

Comment: Thank you for improvement suggestion. I misunderstood keep option,it seems EEOT_RATE is displayed in output variables since it is calculated in output and I don't need keep option. Keep option is useful when I need to keep only a few variables in output for more clarity on certain topics and drops other unnecessary variables. So thanks,this issue was solved as well.